# Typescript error 1005. ':' expected when trying to access returned JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I'm returning `data` from an API call. The returned JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getAccountDetails": {
            "cars": [
                {
                    "rental": true,
                    "id": "abcdefg"                    
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to console log the boolean `rental` (true or false). I keep getting this typescript error: `':' expected. ts(1005`. This is how I'm console logging:

```
console.log(data?.getAccountDetails?.cars?[0]);
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: The error most likely isn't in the code you've shown. Such syntax errors are usually caused by something wrong before or around this line. Please show the full context of where this line of code is used and how.

Comment: You must have made typos, during copy paste. The object you show us has a getAccountDetails attribute, but you try to access the getThermostatDetails. Can you refactor to a more precise code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dot.

```js
console.log(data?.getThermostatDetails?.thermostats?.[0]);
```

It's `?.` even when you want to access a property via square brackets.